# Why does setting color in CSS before fail?

Tags: html, css

Got a checkbox that works fine, but for some browser (Edge, iPad, phone) the color specified on :before item is incorrect (see last line css):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
 display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    content: "\2714";
    border: 0.1em solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: transparent;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: rgb(74,86,46);
    border-color: rgb(74,86,46);
    color: #fff; /* Bad color displayed */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkOne"/>
<label for="checkOne">Test</label>
```

In Edge it is not white but green. On some (smaller) devices it is black. Anybody an idea how to fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could use the devtools and see the default's browser styles that are applied to that element. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: Edge (Version 80.0.361.69) devtool (F12) shows color: #fff but ignores it (whatever color chosen).

Comment: Yeah. I've also tried this issue on the new Edge and doesn't work neither.I've just sent this issue to the edge's team, let's see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

:before isn't supported Safari/ iOS Safari
https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore

Maybe here you can find your solution
[Why :before cannot be seen in safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989772/why-before-cannot-be-seen-in-safari)

Comment: This is wrong. All modern browsers, including (mobile) Safari, [support `::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and have done so for years. The link you posted is about "Animation and transition support" with `::before` but not `::before` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think `::before` is a "Pseudo Element" and there is no class named `:before` or `:after`

Comment: "CSS3 introduced the ::before notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :before, introduced in CSS2." from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)