# CSS animation on :before element doesn't always work (safari)

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation on a :before element and it works in FireFox and Chrome but not in Safari (every now and then it works after clearing the cache multiple times or editing many files). I checked [this link](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=css%20animation) on CanIUse and it appears to be supported in Safari. Maybe there's something I'm missing. Here's what I have so far:

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.3em;
}
.highlight .highlight-inner {
    color: black!important;
    line-height: 1.85;
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideFadeIn {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes slideFadeIn {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.highlight:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.2em;
    bottom: 0.2em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #9085da;

    width: 0;
    animation: slideFadeIn 1.5s cubic-bezier(.22, 1, .32, 1) 0.6s;
    transform-origin: left;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="highlight">
    <span class="highlight-inner">Designing</span>
</span>
```

To see the desired effect, view this page in FireFox or Chrome (it's not an ad): https://www.lavandacode.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this answer maybe it can help you [Why :before cannot be seen in safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17991029/11451001)

Comment: Yeah, I found that answer earlier and had no luck.

Comment: When I opened it with safari, I did not see a problem!

Comment: (I didn't think it was appropriate to solve my own answer because I used a different method) But i fixed my "issue" by replacing the :before element with a separate div. You probably saw it after I fixed it.